# Should you be able to downvote without adding an answer or a comment?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Happy to have people disagree if they state why. Promotes learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another one which keeps coming up on meta.SO. the main answer for it is here. [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/154443)

I don't think there are any plans to change the process

Answer (score 2):

Voting is anonymous, commenting is not. Forcing voters to "come out" and defend their position is undemocratic and will put people off voting.

Incidentally, if you want to raise a specific issue with a post but do not want to publish your complaint in a comment, you can choose to flag the post and describe the issue to the mods instead. It's not anonymous but is private.